# My Wamp LocalHost freezes and I have to restart it every time I fill out a form and enter it?

Tags: php, html, css, localhost, wamp

This never used to happen.. I stopped using my site for a while and then when I came back to it the forms made it freeze and I had to restart the localhost every time I entered one... The code is really long so I was just wondering if anyone else has had this problem and if it is a simple fix?

```
    <div class="title">Application Form</div>
            <form action="apply.php" method="POST">
                <table>
                    <?php
                        if (isset($_POST["fisrtname"])) {
                            $firstname = $_POST["firstname"];
                            $lastname = $_POST["lastname"];
                            $gender = $_POST["gender"];
                            $age = $_POST["age"];
                            $skype = $_POST["skype"];
                            $acc = $_POST["acc"];
                            $about = $_POST["about"];
                            $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                            $subject = "New Application Email";
                            $from = "no-reply@contact-form.com";
                            $message = "
Date/Time: $date
Firstname: $firstname
Lastname: $lastname
Gender: $gender
Age: $age
Skype: $skype
Acc: $acc
About: $about
";
                            // send mail
                            mail("rapidoradioonline@gmail.com", $subject, $message, "From: $from\n");
                            echo "<br><div style='color:red'>Your appication has been sent</div>";
                        }
                    ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td>First Name<i class="req">*</i></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="fisrtname" required></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Last Name<i class="req">*</i></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="lastname" required></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Gender<i class="req">*</i></td>
                        <td><input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" required checked>Male<br><input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" required>Female</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Age<i class="req">*</i></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="age" required></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Skype Name<i class="req">*</i></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="skype" required></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>RapidoRadio Account Name<i class="req">*</i></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="skype" required></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>About yourself(Capabilities, Previous experiences etc.)<i class="req">*</i></td>
                        <td><textarea name="about" required></textarea></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td><input type="submit"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
```

Comment: What changed since you were using the site without a problem?

Comment: I have absolutely no idea.. I'll post the code that I assume isn't working

Comment: The thing is, it isn't just that page, it's every page with a form.

Comment: You could start by sorting out field names like `fisrtname` and `firstname` and 2 fields called `skype` but that should not cause a hang in themselves. Also you are not checking the return status of `mail()` And as you are running on Windows, and that has no mail server by default, what are you using as a mail server??

Comment: http://glob.com.au/sendmail/ I'm using this one